# Caffe is teeing me that the LMDB created by convert_imageset is empty

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, caffe, conv-neural-network

I am working on a CNN.

For that, I need 2 pairs of LMDB's (one for the testing, and one for training).

Each LMDB in the pair are made out of images, where one LMDB contains the GT.

So I make 4 lists of the images and feed this into convert_imageset. After that I feed the LMDB's into caffe. Caffe constructs the training net without a problem, but when it comes to the testing net, it tells me that the file is empty. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: How are you creating you LMDB? Are you doing semantic segmentation?

Comment: Actually, it turned the problem was elsewhere. I had ImageData rather than Data.